# What does malloc do in this situation?

Tags: c, parsing

What does this line of C code do?

```
      be_node *ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
```

The definition of be_node can be found in this file: http://funzix.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=funzix/funzix;a=blob_plain;f=bencode/bencode.h;hb=HEAD

The line of code above was found in this file: http://funzix.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=funzix/funzix;a=blob_plain;f=bencode/bencode.c;hb=HEAD

I don't understand what the sizeof(*ret) would return if it has only just been declared?

Comment: It would return the size of a `be_node`. Because it's `sizeof`, it's not really dereferencing `ret`.

Comment: there is no such thing ! only if *ret is a typedef type.

Comment: @A_nto2 It's actually quite useful in that if you later change `be_node` to something else, you won't have to change the `malloc` argument. (but personally I don't like it much)

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Quite useful, indeed. Supposing it effectively works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's no different to any other use of `sizeof`; it will evaluate the size of its operand.  `sizeof` is based on compile-time information,<sup>1</sup> so it doesn't matter that `ret` has only just been declared.

This idiom is the preferred way of using `malloc`.  If you were to use `be_node *ret = malloc(sizeof(be_node))`, then consider what would happen if you change the type of `ret` at a later date.  If you forget to replace both uses of "`be_node`", then you will have introduced a subtle bug.

---

<sub>1. Except in the case of variable-length arrays.</sub>

Comment: +1, but even more prefered by many would be to omit the parenthesis to make it clear that the `sizeof` operator applies to an expression and not a type name, something like `sizeof *ret`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Maybe.  But that's a style thing, not a maintenance thing.

Comment: Oli, mainly but not completely a style thing. It changes border cases. If you use `sizeof(toto)` in a place where you think you use a variable `toto`, this still would be valid, even if someone changes `toto` to refer to a type.

Comment: @JensGustedt: True.  I hadn't considered that case.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(*ret)` is resolved by the compiler and only looks at the type of `*ret`, not its contents.  In this case, it's the size of a be_node.  It also gets resolved at compile time, not at runtime so it doesn't "return" per se, it just gets substituted with a constant.

The compiler is going to take out `sizeof(*ret)` and substitute in a constant number that is the size of the `be_node` in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shortcut, or whatever you might want to call it.

You can either write

```
be_node *ret = malloc(sizeof(be_node));
```

or

```
be_node *ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
```

In the first case, you're basically saying "allocate a memory block large enough to hold a be_node". In the second case you're saying "allocate a memory block large enough to hold whatever ret points to". Which one you prefer is mostly a matter of preference.

Comment: It's not *just* a matter of preference. As Oli's answer points out, the second form is more robust in the presence of changes to the declaration of `ret`.

Answer (score 1):

sizeof works with both data types and actual variables. In your case, you invoke it with a variable as a parameter. By the time you invoke sizeof the variable is DECLARED (not initialized but declared) so it will know the var's type and will be able to compute the memory requirements in bytes which will be returned and used by the malloc.

Comment: No. `malloc` only works with arguments that are `size_t`. This situation works because the `sizeof` operator can take an expression (such as in `sizeof *ret`) or a parenthesized type (such as in `sizeof(be_node)`).

Comment: yes, my bad! I meant sizeof can take as parameter either a var or a type. And I think you understood that. If you did ... I will edit my answer and you will vote it up! Deal ?

Comment: The operand of the `sizeof` operator is either a parenthesized type name (as in `sizeof (int)`) or an expression. The expression doesn't have to be a variable name. For example, `sizeof 42` is equivalent to `sizeof (int)`.

Comment: I agree it can take an expression but I really don't see the point of passing an expression as a parameter/operand to sizeof.
This guy uses my wording :).

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Comment: Well... that guy is talking about some language called C++. ;)

The C standard refers to expressions, so that's the terminology I'd use, personally. But +1 for fixing the answer.